# Can we give direction to the electron released from the use of photoelectric effect?

Tags: particle-physics, photoelectric-effect

I wanted to build an electron accelerator and wanted to isolate a single electron. So, if I provide right amount of energy to the metal, would I be able to isolate the electron WHILE making it move in the direction intended?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by isolating.

Comment: You can apply an electric field

Answer (score 0):

Electron emission due to photoelectric effect doesn't have any specific direction. To give it a certain direction, you can use a setup similar to X-Ray production. The schematic diagram for it is as shown below.

[image]

In X-Rays to give a certain direction, a "Collimator" is used. You may like to use a similar setup. The only difference in the setup of X-Rays and Your Setup will be that in X-Rays Thermionic Emission is used to produce electrons and in Your Setup, Photoelectric Effect will be used.

In thermionic emission also there is no specific direction the electron takes. Electrons pop-out like popcorns from the oven and then they are given direction with the help of a collimator.

You may like to read more on the experimental setup of X-Rays at any of the standard textbooks.